# Elasticsearch-PHP application not working

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch-PHP application and it works locally. However, when I put it on an RHEL 6 server that only supports PHP 5.3, it does not work. When I go to the console, I get GET http://xx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxx/init.php 500 (Internal Server Error). The problem I think might be from a connection issue in the init.php. Here's the code inside init.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

/*Build connection*/
$hosts = [
'xx.x.xxx.xxx',                // Port
];

$es = ClientBuilder::create()    // Instantiate a new ClientBuilder
        ->setHosts($hosts)      // Set the hosts
        ->build();             // Build the client object

?>
```

This works perfect locally. I don't know why it doesn't work when I transfer it to the server.

Comment: What's the configuration of your ES server?

Comment: @Val I don't think it's a configuration issue with the ES server, I think the issue is with PHP not recognizing the code. I tried running this code on PHP 5.3.10 and it gives me this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\wamp\www\test3\es.php on line 6` line 6 is where it says `$hosts = [` it is not recognizing the syntax

Comment: What PHP version do you have on your localhost?

Comment: @Val I used PHP 7 and then experimented with 5.6, both worked fine. I then installed PHP 5.3.10 and it gave me that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 5.3.10 the short array syntax was not available, you can simply fix your code by using `array()` instead:

```
$hosts = array(
    'xx.x.xxx.xxx',                // Port
);
```

Comment: Hmm, you're right...Gotta fix all the Elasticsearch files now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Or better, upgrade PHP, as 5.3.10 is quite old and subject to other bugs.

Comment: I want to, but I'm working for an organization that uses PHP 5.3.3 in their RHEL 6 server. It seems that nothing other than 5.3.3 is supported on it